# How to detect a player’s x coordinate and teleport them to the other side of the map in 1.15.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Minecraft Earth map and I want it so if you go too far on one side, it will teleport you to the other side: so players can get from Japan to America by going through the Pacific Ocean. I tried the following command, but it didn't work. What should I do?

```
/execute as @e[x=5375,y=~,z=~,distance=..2] at @s run tp @s ~-10750 ~ ~
```

Comment: Did you get an error message? If so, what was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tilde notation with `~` is not available in target selectors, and even if it was supported, it wouldn't work, because the tilde is relative to the command block, not to the players selected.

What I would do is use a rectangular volume to make this work.

```
... as @e[x=5375,y=64,z=10,dx=0,dy=999,dz=999]
```

This makes a giant selection box starting at coordinates (5375, 64,10) and extending one block east, 1000 blocks up, and 1000 blocks south (an implicit `1` is added to all 3 delta values).

To determine `x`, `y`, and `z`, go to the lower northwest corner of your selection box. `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` should be the number of blocks east, up, and south to extend the border wall.

Comment: I did what you said, and got no error message, but when I go through the area, nothing happens, no teleportation takes place

Comment: @Wera Are you absolutely sure you got the numbers correct? Make sure `x`, `y`, and `z` represent the *lower northwest corner* of the target box. Also make sure to substitute the correct values in for `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`.

Comment: actually nvm! Eye made a mistake, eye made dx dy dz the coordinate of the top east south corner, instead of how far to expand the box eye fixed it, thank you so much :>

Comment: @Wera If this answer solved your problem, please click the gray check mark on this answer to indicate that your problem is now solved

Answer (score 1):

For my method, we will use scoreboards.  First you must make a scoreboard with a dummy critera we'll name it `xpos`.  Then you have to put it in a **repeating command block or in a ticking function** (a function running every tick) the following command.

```
execute as @a at @s store result score @s xpos run data get entity @s Pos[0]
```

That will at every tick store the x value of every player in the world to their scoreboard value.  This is multiplayer friendly.  Next, we test if they have a specific value or a range in the scoreboard with the following command.

```
execute as @a[scores={xpos=<range/value>}] at @s run tp <cordinates>
```

Keep in mind, for this to work, **both commands I gave you must be in a repeating command block or in a ticking function**.  In your case replace `<range/value>` with `5375..` and `<cordinates>` to `-5375 ~ ~`.  If you have any questions please ask I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Works for an infinitely long border, but is unnecessary if the border has a finite length.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 but it is better for lag.